# Hide text in a web page, displaying it when selected

Tags: html, css

I've a personnal page : http://matthieu.riegler.fr/index.html

I want to hide a "little" trollface in it who only shows up when the text is selected.

Any idea how I could do it properly.

That's what I have.

```
#trollface {
float:left;
color: #F5FAFF; /* color of my background */
margin-top: -45em;
}
```

It works but it's a bit messy I think.

So any idea to help me ? :)

Thx

Comment: "*It works but it's a bit **messy** I think.*" Why is it messy? What else do you need?

Comment: For example I'd like to hide the texte when it's selected. And I'm no expert in CSS so I don't know if there is a better way than I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target selected text for css rules:

```
*::selection {
    color: ...
}
*::-moz-selection {
    color: ...
}
```

You could try putting your background image in that way.

Comment: Hum, it works nice on Chrome, but -moz-selection seems to have no effect on my update-to-date Firefox :/

Comment: My mistake, it works. But the thing the selection is still messy. It selects the original text and the trollface text. Is there no better way than with the margin ?